# How to set contentEditable property in aspx?

Tags: asp.net

I need to make a text box related to a calender control readonly.
I set the contentEditable property to false. Still it can be edited.
Here Readonly property failed to support my solution.
Can any one please help me out?

'
                                                                              contentEditable="False"  MaxLength="10" />

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
contentEditable="False" 
onKeyPress = "javascript: return false;" 
onPaste = "javascript: return false;"
```

You can try this one. Here the contentEditable property is browser dependent. So for browsers other than IE

```
onKeyPress = "javascript: return false;" 
onPaste = "javascript: return false;"
```

will do the job